# Server returning MP4 as plaintext

Tags: php

I have a script that uploads files and it mainly uploads MP4's. I can see the file has been uploaded into the correct place and also am able to download it and it plays ok. However, when trying to locate to the files location, nothing seems to happen. It also appears to be returning a mime type of text/plain; charset=UTF-8.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you should use a different mime type..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "trying to locate to the files location"?

Comment: When i go to the files location via the URL

Comment: Post some code so many more people can help you. Where do you upload, directory or database? (only do the former). The specific upload file and download would be the best (;

Answer (score 1):

You can set your header as follows with php:

```
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-type: video/mpeg');
header('Content-disposition: inline');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:­ binary");
```

This should work...

Comment: The problem is, is that i shouldn't have to set the content type of a file. I never needed to do this before on a different server. So wondering if a server setting would cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache config file(or .htaccess) you can define a mime type for mp4 to force the download. The correct mime-type for *.m4p is "video/mp4".

To force download use

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
```

Or correct mime

```
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
```